# Monitor Multiple variables in one subscription Node OPC-UA

Tags: opc-ua, opc, node-opcua

I am Using [NodeOPCUA](https://node-opcua.github.io) To detect Variable change,So i am using this code as ref
https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/master/documentation/creating_a_client_callback.md
Every thing is working fine, only i need to is it possible to monitor multiple  Variable value change in one subscription ,if possible please share the ideas, Thanks

Comment: Did you try to simply create multiple Monitored Items like described here https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/blob/master/documentation/creating_a_client_callback.md#add-some-monitored-items ?